# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context androidx.fragment.app.FragmentHostCallback.getContext()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I have data, I transfer it from mainActivity to homefragment which is inside FragmentContainerView
Then I use BottomNavigationView to move between other fragments inside FragmentContainerView, but I get the following error
And when I remove the code to send data to homefragment, it works fine.
Is there a solution to make the two work together at the same time?

Error

```
Process: com.example.onestore, PID: 7385
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context androidx.fragment.app.FragmentHostCallback.getContext()' on a null object reference
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$3.instantiate(FragmentManager.java:507)
at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.createFragmentTransaction(FragmentNavigator.kt:250)
at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.navigate(FragmentNavigator.kt:185)
at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.navigate(FragmentNavigator.kt:164)
at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigateInternal(NavController.kt:260)
at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1719)
at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1545)
at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1472)
at androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(NavigationUI.kt:92)
at com.example.onestore.MainActivity.onCreate$lambda$2(MainActivity.kt:45)
at com.example.onestore.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$p3Ght_wmrnZ4Tl5QQoEfelfbqjI(Unknown Source:0)
at com.example.onestore.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onNavigationItemSelected(Unknown Source:4)
at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationBarView$1.onMenuItemSelected(NavigationBarView.java:291)
at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:836)
at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:159)
at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:987)
at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationBarMenuView$1.onClick(NavigationBarMenuView.java:139)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

mainActivity

```
 class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding : ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding=ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        //Data received
        val bundle = intent.extras
        val Datas = bundle?.getParcelable("EXTRA_SESSION_ID") as? Datahome
        Datas?.result?.home_1?.let { Log.i("TAA", it.title) }

       //send Data to homeFragment
        val MyData = Datas
        val fragment = MyData?.let { HomeFragment.newInstance(it) }

        if (fragment != null) {
            supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragmentContainerView2,fragment )
                .commit()
        }
        val navHomeFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainerView2) as NavHostFragment
        binding.bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navHomeFragment.navController)
        binding.bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener { item ->
            Log.i("BF" ,item.toString())

            binding.bottomNavigationView.menu.findItem(item.itemId).isChecked = false
            NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item,navHomeFragment.navController)
            return@setOnItemSelectedListener false
        }

        setContentView(binding.root)

    }
}
```

homeFargment

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentHomeBinding
    
    companion object {
        fun newInstance(yourData: Datahome) = HomeFragment().apply {
            arguments = Bundle().apply { putParcelable("Key", yourData) }
        }

        }


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        //receive Data From BaseFragment
        val data : Datahome? = arguments?.getParcelable("Key")
        if (data != null) {
            insertData(data)
        }
        
    }
```

activity main

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView.PrimarySurface"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        app:elevation="50dp"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/bottom_nav_background"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_nav_item"
        app:itemPaddingBottom="5dp"
        app:itemPaddingTop="2dp"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_nav_item"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/botton_nav_menu" />

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView2"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:context=".BaseFragment"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

nav-Grap

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:name="com.example.onestore.Fragment.HomeFragment"
        android:label="fragment_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/CategoryFragment"
        android:name="com.example.onestore.Fragment.categortFragment"
        android:label="fragment_categort"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_categort" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/SearchFragment"
        android:name="com.example.onestore.Fragment.SearchFragment"
        android:label="fragment_search"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_search" />
</navigation>
```

menu

```
   <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_home_24"
        android:title="@string/home"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/CategoryFragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_category_24"
        android:title="@string/category" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/SearchFragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_search_24"
        android:title="@string/search" />

  </menu>
```

Comment: You should not be doing any FragmentTransactions at all ever if you are using the Navigation Component. Why are you doing any of that? What happens if you remove all of that code?

Comment: I want to transfer data from activity to fragment.
I can also move between fragments